# Change the starter for loop index

Tags: shell, for-loop

I want to compare two lists without recombination in shell script:

```
A=(a b c d e)
B=(b c d e f)
```

then print a combination

```
ab
ac
ad
ae
af

bc
bd
be
bf

...


de
df

ef
```

I am tried with 'for ' loop

------------------------CODE----------------------------------------

```
arr_a=(a b c d e f)


for i in 0 1 2 3 4
do


jdx=$(( $i + 1 ))


        for j in {$jdx..5}        
        do

        echo ${arr_a[$i]}'_'${arr_a[$j]}

        done

done
```

--------------------END CODE ------------------------------------

But the problem is `$jdx`.

Any hints to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the exact problem with $jdx? What values are you receiving from the code, and what are you expecting in place of the incorrect output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) to do this:

```
$ A=(a b c d e)
$ B=(b c d e f)
$ eval echo $(echo {${A[@]}}{${B[@]}} | tr ' ' ',')
ab ac ad ae af bb bc bd be bf cb cc cd ce cf db dc dd de df eb ec ed ee ef
```

This is first outputting the arrays in the form `{a,b,c,d,e}{b,c,d,e,f}`, then brace expansion takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Use  C-style for loops:

```
for ((i=0; i < ${#A[@]}; i++)); do  
    for ((j=i; j < ${#B[@]}; j++)); do
        echo ${A[i]}${B[j]}
    done
    echo
done
```

```
ab
ac
ad
ae
af

bc
bd
be
bf

cd
ce
cf

de
df

ef
```